# How to create .deb packages on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, deb, dpkg

I am trying to upload my app on Cydia and it requires .deb package. I am unable to figure out how to make .deb packages on mac. I am using 10.6.3 when I write this command on terminal

```
dpkg-deb -b MyProgram
```

Terminal output is

```
-bash: dpkg-deb: command not found
```

I've install fink, Mac ports insert Mac DVD to find out but nothing helps.

Comment: Without a pressing reason would not suggest using both MacPorts and Fink.. Now, I'm a Fink Rat, but I'm willing to bet that Juri is a Port Pusher. Which you want is a function of what package you *need* and which style you prefer. In either case you'll need XCode.

Comment: BTW-- I'm going to disagree with the off-topic votes. Building packages is part of the development process. We don't hold questions about tools for building windows installers as off-topic, do we?

Comment: I've installed macports and run this command dpkg-deb -b MyProgram
 but I get this error warning, 
dpkg-deb: ignoring 3 warnings about the control file(s)
Can't use format gnu: No such format 'gnu': Invalid argument
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar --help
dpkg-deb: subprocess tar -cf returned error exit status 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I installed mac ports 1.7 through terminal as no package is available.

After that I installed Mac ports 1.9 through installer.

Then goto this path `/opt/local/bin` and run `sudo port selfupdate`

after that execute `sudo port install dpkg`

it will take some time and after that your dpkg is successfully configured.

Run this command `sudo dpkg-deb -b MyProgram` to make MyProgram.deb

Note MyProgram should contain DEBIAN folder and under that control file remove txt extention

Below is control file

```
Website: www.zeeshanullah.com
Maintainer: zeeshanullah <zzeeshann@gmail.com>
Name: Snapture
Package: zeeshanullah
Section: zeeshanullah
Version: 2.x.x
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Description: GPS joke.
Sponsor: zeeshanullah.com <zeeshanullah>
```

dont forget to place a new line at the end of control file otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: I've installed macports and run this command dpkg-deb -b MyProgram
 but I get this error warning, 
dpkg-deb: ignoring 3 warnings about the control file(s)
Can't use format gnu: No such format 'gnu': Invalid argument
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar --help
dpkg-deb: subprocess tar -cf returned error exit status 1

Comment: why would you use macports?

Answer (score 40):

It's available on Homebrew:

`brew install dpkg`

If you don't have Homebrew installed, go to [brew.sh](https://brew.sh/). It's a simple one-liner to install.

Homebrew is less invasive, less complicated, and more popular than Macports or similar.

Answer (score 3):

You need Xcode installed on your system before using mac ports - you find it on the second mac DVD, I think. After that, you can install mac ports and then via the Terminal type "sudo port install dpkg", press return and enter your password. It may take some time to compile. You tried that?

Comment: If he's got fink as well he *already* has dpkg, because fink is apt based.

Comment: I've installed Mac ports 1.9.1 and xcode when I run this command

Comment: Zeeshan-ullahs-MacBook-Pro:/ zeeshanullah$ sudo port install dpgk
Error: Port dpgk not found
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>

Comment: I've installed Mac ports 1.9.1 and xcode when I run this command When I run this command sudo port install dpgk I found Zeeshan-ullahs-MacBook-Pro:/ zeeshanullah$ sudo port install dpgk Error: Port dpgk not found To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>

Comment: I've installed macports and run this command dpkg-deb -b MyProgram
 but I get this error warning, 
dpkg-deb: ignoring 3 warnings about the control file(s)
Can't use format gnu: No such format 'gnu': Invalid argument
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar --help
dpkg-deb: subprocess tar -cf returned error exit status 1

Answer (score 3):

Best option is to use FPM and you can create it in 50 secs:
[fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm#readme)

Answer (score 0):

i think these links can be useful for you:

[How to make a deb on mac](https://synthesize.us/HOWTO_make_a_deb_archive_without_dpkg)

[Using ant to create deb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576265/creating-a-deb-with-apache-ant-and-without-dpkg)