# Mac OS .deb packaging trouble

Tags: iphone, macos, cydia, deb, dpkg

I've searched a lot, but didn't find the solution.

I need to package my ios app into `.deb`.
I have installed Mac Ports and `dpkg`, I have control file in DEBIAN folder in MyApp folder
I run `/opt/local/bin/dpkg-deb -b MyApp` and get error.

> dpkg-deb: ignoring 3 warnings about the control file(s)
>
> **Can't use format gnu: No such format 'gnu': Invalid argument**

There is another topic: [How to create .deb packages on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989466/how-to-create-deb-packages-on-mac-os-x), but no answer to this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create .deb packages on Mac OS X ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989466/how-to-create-deb-packages-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: no, there were no answer to my question as I said

Comment: It may help to explain why you want to do this. Obviously iOS can't install debs; are you just trying to make a deb on OS X which happens to contain your .ipa file?

Comment: Apologies; you must be talking about making Cydia debs. I didn't make that connection in my head.

Comment: You need to post your DEBIAN/changelog and DEBIAN/control, otherwise is hard to help you.

Comment: Also, I would consider using dpkg-buildpackage (dpkg-dev) instead of dpkg-deb.
Packages build using dpkg-deb lack some features, like ms5sums, and might give you trouble when you try to put it in a apt server.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a tar implementation that does not support the GNU tar fotrmat, which `dpkg-deb` expects for its usage.

You should install GNU tar and either recompile `dpkg` to use that (usually named gtar) instead of simply the executable tar, or prepare a PATH environment to prefer the GNU tar when using `dpkg-deb`.

Newer `dpkg` versions detect this requirement at build time and will abort the build, to make sure this does not happen.