# Creating a .deb with Apache Ant and without dpkg

Tags: ant, deb, dpkg, unix-ar

I'm trying to create a buildfile for creating .deb installation files.

So far, so fine. My goal is to avoid dpkg, so that the build can be done from any plattform.

Now that I created all the artifacts (control.tar.gz, data.tar.gz, debian-binary) I need an Ant-Task to package these Files in a deb-File.

A deb File is just an Ar(l)-Archive, but I couldn't figure out how to create such an Archive with Ant.

I just found some "ArFileSet", so I think there is a possibility, but I don't know how and where to use this arFileSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the thirdparty Ant tasks for building .deb packages:

- [ant-deb-task](http://code.google.com/p/ant-deb-task/)
- [JDeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb)