# MacPorts Install dpkg Errors

Tags: macos, dpkg, theos

**Update:**

`sudo port selfupdate` did not return any errors. This was the output:

```
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
--->  MacPorts base is already the latest version

The ports tree has been updated. To upgrade your installed ports, you should run
  port upgrade outdated
```

However, when I ran `sudo port upgrade outdated`, I got the following error:

```
--->  Configuring expat
Error: org.macports.configure for port expat returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port expat for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

Running `sudo port upgrade gettext` returned the following error:

```
--->  Configuring expat
Error: org.macports.configure for port expat returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port expat for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

**Original Question:**

I'm currently trying to install `dpkg` on my Mac OS 10.7.5, so I can run theos `sudo make package` (it's telling me that I can't do so becuase `dkpg` is not installed).

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989466/how-to-create-deb-packages-on-mac-os-x/4004482#3989466), but I'm running into a problem when I run `sudo port install dpkg`. This is the error:

```
--->  Configuring expat
Error: org.macports.configure for port expat returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port expat for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade gettext failed
```

This is the contents of `main.log`:

```
version:1
:debug:main expat has no conflicts
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (expat)
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 502
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.archivefetch (expat)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (expat)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (expat)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.extract (expat)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.patch (expat)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:configure configure phase started at Wed Mar 13 14:55:32 CDT 2013
:notice:configure --->  Configuring expat
:debug:configure Using compiler 'Mac OS X clang'
:debug:configure Executing org.macports.configure (expat)
:debug:configure Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -arch x86_64' CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/local/include' CXXFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -arch x86_64' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.7' CXX='/usr/bin/clang++' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' F90FLAGS='-pipe -O2 -m64' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/local/lib -arch x86_64' OBJC='/usr/bin/clang' FCFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -m64' INSTALL='/usr/bin/install -c' OBJCFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -arch x86_64' FFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -m64' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' CC='/usr/bin/clang'
:debug:configure Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/expat-2.1.0" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local'
:debug:configure Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/expat-2.1.0" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local 
:info:configure sh: line 0: cd: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/expat-2.1.0: No such file or directory
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/expat-2.1.0" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local 
:info:configure Exit code: 1
:error:configure org.macports.configure for port expat returned: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: command execution failed
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: targets not executed for expat: org.macports.install org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot
:notice:configure Please see the log file for port expat for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
```

Could anyone help me get `dpkg` installed? I have absolutely no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Did you run `sudo port selfupdate` first? Also what version of `gettext` do you have installed? Did you attempt to `sudo port upgrade gettext`?

Comment: I tried `sudo port selfupdate`, and that worked fine. However, I did get an error when I tried `sudo port upgrade outdated`. I'll update my question.

Comment: Also, `sudo port upgrade gettext` returns an error as well. It seems that the error for `upgrade gettext` and `upgrade outdated` are the same.

Comment: This just reconfirms my happiness at using *brew* instead of *port* on OS X machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing dpkg using `brew` instead of `port`, as was suggested by Randy Howard.

Link here: [http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/](https://brew.sh)

As Randy suggested, getting Brew up and running was a lot easier than using MacPorts. After uninstalling the latter, I ran the ruby code given at the page above, and was able to install `dpkg` within a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue so just uninstalled the whole lot

`sudo port -fp uninstall installed`

Got the package I was after installed now so might be worth a go

https://www.macports.org/guide/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem today as well - and ended up removing the .macports.expat.state file in /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work, and doing a 'port fetch expat' manually to make sure the latest was being brought over. Seemed it was having a hard time with 2.1.0.

After doing this, was able to do a straight 'port upgrade expat', which finally upgraded correctly.

Not really sure why it was having a problem with expat 2.1.0 upgrade.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I upgraded to OX10.9, and having trouble with expat too. However, gnutar is now the blocker. Attempting to install gnutar. I am now in vicious circle with gettext, expat and gnutar.

Comment: Found solution to OX 10.9 Mavericks update. Just not thinking straight on a Friday. The solution is to update to the OS X 10.9 Mavericks:
MacPorts-2.2.1-10.9-Mavericks.pkg at http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html . Do this and the expat, apr, gnutar, etc... will update just fine.